# Can web components handle CSS (cssChangedCallback?)

Tags: javascript, css, web-component

Is there any way to handle how CSS is applied to a web component like you can do with attributes using [attributeChangedCallback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements#Using_the_lifecycle_callbacks).

I am working on a couple web components that would benefit from being styled with CSS classes, but I need to change multiple styles for it to look correct (e.g. if you set the color of the control, the user would expect the border color of one element and the font color of another to change in the shadow DOM).

---

Is there any way to get `.usingCSS { color: red; }` to change the color of the toggle switch in the following simple web component example?

```js
// based on https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_switch.asp

class W3schoolsToggleSwitch extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    var shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
    this.span = document.createElement("span");
    this.span.innerHTML = `
    <style>
      /* The switch - the box around the slider */
      .switch {
        --color: #2196F3;
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 60px;
        height: 34px;
      }

      /* Hide default HTML checkbox */
      .switch input {
        opacity: 0;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
      }

      /* The slider */
      .slider {
        position: absolute;
        cursor: pointer;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        background-color: #ccc;
        -webkit-transition: .4s;
        transition: .4s;
      }

      .slider:before {
        position: absolute;
        content: "";
        height: 26px;
        width: 26px;
        left: 4px;
        bottom: 4px;
        background-color: white;
        -webkit-transition: .4s;
        transition: .4s;
      }

      input:checked + .slider {
        background-color: var(--color);
      }

      input:focus + .slider {
        box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
      }

      input:checked + .slider:before {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
        -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
        transform: translateX(26px);
      }

      /* Rounded sliders */
      .slider.round {
        border-radius: 34px;
      }

      .slider.round:before {
        border-radius: 50%;
      }
    </style>
    <label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox" checked>
        <span class="slider round"></span>
    </label>
    `;
    shadow.appendChild(this.span);
  }

  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ["color"];
  }

  attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
    console.log(name, newValue);
    if ("color" === name) {
      this.shadowRoot
        .querySelector(".switch")
        .style.setProperty("--color", newValue);
    }
  }

  get color() {
    return this.getAttribute("color");
  }

  set color(value) {
    return this.setAttribute("color", value);
  }
}

customElements.define("w3schools-toggle-switch", W3schoolsToggleSwitch);
```

```css
.usingCSS {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
default:
<w3schools-toggle-switch></w3schools-toggle-switch>

<br><br> color attribute used to change the color to green:
<w3schools-toggle-switch color="green"></w3schools-toggle-switch>

<br><br> can you change the color with CSS?:
<w3schools-toggle-switch class="usingCSS"></w3schools-toggle-switch>
```

Comment: I would warn you against using an w3Schools resource, especially for anything new. They've had a really awful track record for publishing piss-poor content. That being said, vanilla web components do not ship with a mechanism for handling styles. You'll have to roll your own, or find a library. I'm not aware of any lightweight libraries that will work with web components.

Comment: Do you know of any libraries even if they are not ideal so I can get an idea of how other people are doing it? FYI, I am not using w3schools code in my stuff. I just wanted a simple example since my code is more complex.

Answer (score 1):

**From the outside with `<`link`>`**

You could apply CSS style to a Web Component uning a `<link>` element in the Shadow DOM.

```
#shadow-root
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="default.css">

attributeChangedCallback( name, old, value ) {
   if (name === 'class') 
      this.shadowRoot.querySelector( 'link' ).href = value + ".css"

}
```

**With style defined inside Shadow DOM [:host()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:host()) pseudo-class function**

You can apply different styles based on the context. You can combine multiple classes.

```js
customElements.define( 'custom-element', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.attachShadow( { mode: 'open' } )
        .innerHTML = `
          <style>
            :host( .red ) { color: red }
            :host( .blue ) { color: blue }
            :host( .border ) { border: 1px solid }
          </style>
          Hello`
  }
} )

ce1.onclick = ev => ev.target.classList.add( 'border' )
```

```html
<custom-element class="red" id="ce1"></custom-element>
<custom-element class="blue border"></custom-element>
```

**On Chrome / Opera: with [Constructable stylesheets](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/02/constructable-stylesheets#using_constructed_stylesheets)**

Create one (or several)  Stylesheet(s) and apply it(them) to the Shadow DOM. You can apply multiple stylesheets to the same Shadow DOM.

```js
var ss = []
ss['red'] = new CSSStyleSheet
ss.red.replaceSync( 'span { color: red }' ) 
ss['green'] = new CSSStyleSheet
ss.green.replaceSync( 'span { color: green }' ) 
ss['border'] = new CSSStyleSheet
ss.border.replaceSync( 'span { border: 1px solid }' ) 

customElements.define( 'custom-element', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.attachShadow( { mode: 'open' } )
        .innerHTML = `<span>Hello</span>`
  }
  
  static get observedAttributes() { return [ 'class' ] }
  
  attributeChangedCallback() {
    this.shadowRoot.adoptedStyleSheets = [ ...this.classList ].map( cl => ss[ cl ] )
  }
} )

ce1.onclick = ev => ev.target.classList.add( 'border' )
```

```html
<custom-element class="red" id="ce1"></custom-element>
<custom-element class="green border"></custom-element>
```

Comment: This is a clever solution, but I was hoping for something more generic. For this to work, I would need to know all the classes that will be set ahead of time so I could add code to map them. I work on a framework so I was hoping for something more along the lines of mapping a single CSS property to a group of properties rather than mapping a pre-defined class to properties. I will keep this in mind if there is not a more generic option as it could be a good partial solution to my problem. Thanks!

Comment: @lBahr I gave examples with 1 class but you can define as much classes as you want

Comment: I understand that I can have as many classes as I want, but the fact still stands that I must create a new class for every possible state. If I want a state for every color then I would need to define a class for every single color which will not work for my case since I work on an internal company framework.

Answer (score 1):

Extending on Supersharps answer.

when you can not use Constructable Stylesheets yet:

You could (brutally) import a whole STYLE definition from the Host document.

`onload=this.disabled=true` to prevent styling the document DOM

or create a `<my-themes></my-themes>` Component that hosts (and serves) the `STYLE` elements

```js
customElements.define( 'custom-element', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.root=this.attachShadow( { mode: 'open' } );
    this.root.innerHTML = `<style>div{font-size:40px}</style>`
                         +`<style id="theme"></style><div>Click Me</div>`;
    let themes = window.themes;//duplicate IDs create a global NodeList
    let themeNr = 0;
    this.root.addEventListener('click', ev => 
       this.theme = themes[ themeNr<themes.length ? themeNr++ : themeNr=0 ].innerHTML);
  }
  set theme(css){
    this.root.getElementById('theme').innerHTML = css;
  }
} )
```

```html
<style id="themes" onload="this.disabled=true">
  div{
    background:yellow;
  }
</style>
<style id="themes" onload="this.disabled=true">
  div{
    background:hotpink;
    font-size:30px;
  }
</style>
<style id="themes" onload="this.disabled=true">
  div{
    background:red;
    color:white;
  }
  div::after{
    content:" theme2"
  }
</style>
<custom-element></custom-element>
<custom-element></custom-element>
<custom-element></custom-element>
<div>Main Document</div>
```

Comment: This is a really cool idea, but it has the same limitation that I would need to define a class for every state. For example if I wanted my control to have different colors then I would need to create a class for every color. I see how this could be useful, just not for my case.

Comment: I presume you know ``--customColor:red`` CSS properties can be global **and** be accessed inside shadowDOM ``color: var(--customColor,blue)``

Comment: Yes. That is the best solution I have found so far. It works fine. I am just surprised that this is not possible. I did find an interesting post about watching for style changes https://dev.to/oleggromov/observing-style-changes---d4f. It is not a production ready solution in my opinion, but is closer to my ideal solution.